# check & convert from a string to date vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, date-format

I am a beginner in VB.NET & I am stuck at a very simple thing, Date formats.

I am working on an application which uploads data from excel sheets into sql server database. The application will accept dates only if they are in mm/dd/yyyy format. It should reject all dates otherwise.

Now i am struggling to check its format. Here is my code.

```
Dim ROHSDate As String
ROHSDate = Trim(filterString(holdingTank))
... 
here i need to check if it is in mm/dd/yyyy format
```

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx), which allows you to specify the format - it will attempt to parse it, putting the parsed value into an output parameter on success, and return success/failure:

```
Dim dt As DateTime
If (DateTime.TryParseExact(ROHSDate, "mm/dd/yyyy", \
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, \
                           DateTimeStyles.None, \
                           Out dt))
    UseDateTime(dt)
End If
```

Obviously, add `Else` clauses etc if you need them.

(I believe in modern VB the line continuations may be unnecessary, but hey... hopefully you get the point.)

Note that I've explicitly used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` so that if the code is running on a machine which uses different date separators or a different calendar, it won't make any difference.